# Can't find neither FormsSigninPage or IdentityModelSignInPageBase classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, fba

I'm trying to customize my signin page on Sharepoint 2013, I'm using VS2012 and I've create an WebPart solution. I've added an Application page and when try to add the Assembly 'Microsoft.Sharepoint.Identity' reference to the project I can't find it.

What I'm missing?

I've checked the GAC list and the assembly is registered. I've searched the assembly on the the disk and can't find it, only the windows/assembly reference folder.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've found it by now - however if any other googlers should stumble upoon this page, mine is at: `\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll`